# R - Building a "supported currencies" list from currency pairs

Tags: r

I'm struggling with a loop in R and I don't know how to address my problem. I have a data frame with three columns like this:

```
  base_currency quote_currency       api_key
1           USD            AUD      USDAUD13
2           USD            CAD      USDCAD58
3           EUR            CNY      EURCNY99
4           EUR            CZK      EURCZK65
5           USD            EUR      USDEUR45
6           JPY            HKD      JPYHKD33
7           JPY            RUB      JPYRUB83
```

These are all currency pairs for which I have a data source to get exchange rates through an API. As you can see I can convert `USD` in `AUD` (and backwards), `USD` in `CAD` (and backwards) etc.

I can't directly convert `USD` in `CNY` but since I can convert `USD` in `EUR` and then `EUR` in `CNY`, I can handle the conversion using intermediate currency pairs.

Using this system I can similarily convert `AUD` in `CAD` usig the `USD/AUD` and `USD/CAD` pairs. Actually, every currency in the first 5 rows can be converted in any currency prensent in those same rows.

My data frame may also contains currency pairs that are isolated from this "system" like `JPY/HKD` and `JPY/RUB`. Through those currency pairs I can get HKD/RUB but that's it. The only way that second "system" of currency pairs could be linked to the first one is to share one of it's currency in either the `base_currency` column or in the `quote_currency` column.

My objective is to define a "supported currencies" list. This list would contain the currencies that could be converted into any of the other currencies in that list.

I can see that my data frame present two solutions for that problem :

```
[1] "USD" "AUD" "CAD" "EUR" "CNY" "CZK"
[2] "JPY" "HKD" "RUB"
```

The solution that I'm interested in is the first one, because it contains "USD".

My real data.frame contains more than 100 currency pairs, some are redundant from different data sources.

To give you a little more info about the context, I'm building a really basic stock portfolio manager using Shiny:

1. In the settings, the user can specify the "portfolio currency" with a dropdown item list.
2. When adding a stock to the portfolio, the user must specify the stock's currency from a similar dropdown item list.

I really want to use that "supported currencies" list to build my dropdown menus so they can be dynamically updated when I add a currency pair to the data frame.

For instance if I ever add `USD/JPY` to the dataframe my dropdown menus will show those choices:

```
"USD" "AUD" "CAD" "EUR" "CNY" "CZK" "JPY" "HKD" "RUB"
```

This task seems far too complicated for my modest R skills so I would really appreciate a little help.

Thank you very much !

**@Cedric**
Thank you so much for your answer. I edited your code to add extra fake currency pairs to check how it reacted and something doesn't work:

```
v<-"base_currency;quote_currency;api_key
1;USD;AUD;USDAUD13
2;USD;CAD;USDCAD58
3;EUR;CNY;EURCNY99
4;EUR;CZK;EURCZK65
5;USD;EUR;USDEUR45
6;JPY;HKD;JPYHKD33
7;JPY;RUB;JPYRUB83
8;ALL;AKU;ALLAKU24
9;AKU;RRR;AKURRR96
10;KKL;LOI;KKLLOI46"

d<-read.delim(textConnection(v),header=TRUE,sep=";",strip.white=TRUE,stringsAsFactors =F)


## (1) check for values appearing in both columns
## those will be linked
mm <- d$base_currency%in%d$quote_currency | d$quote_currency%in%d$base_currency
currency_both_sides<-unique(c(d$base_currency[mm],d$quote_currency[mm]))
## (2) find remaining (unlinked) matching pairs for those
d1<-d$base_currency[d$quote_currency%in%currency_both_sides]
d2<-d$quote_currency[d$base_currency%in%currency_both_sides]
(common <- unique(c(d1,d2,currency_both_sides)))
# "EUR" "USD" "ALL" "AKU" "AUD" "CAD" "CNY" "CZK" "RRR"
## (3) the other will only appear on one side
## Here I'm showing all but in the end it will be every single value,
## with all it's matching value in the second column
## they will form separate sets
nn <- !d$base_currency%in%common | !d$quote_currency%in%common
(onesided<-unique(c(d$base_currency[nn],d$quote_currency[nn])))
# "JPY" "KKL" "HKD" "RUB" "LOI"
```

The `common` vector (`"EUR" "USD" "ALL" "AKU" "AUD" "CAD" "CNY" "CZK" "RRR"`) contains `ALL`, `AKU` and `RRR`. These 3 currencies can be converted into each others but not into any of the other currencies in that vector, thus they should not appear in the list. Do you have any idea ?
Again, Thank you so much for your help.

**UPDATE**
I tried something that seems to go in the right direction :

```
v<-"base_currency;quote_currency;api_key
1;USD;AUD;USDAUD13
2;USD;CAD;USDCAD58
3;EUR;CNY;EURCNY99
4;EUR;CZK;EURCZK65
5;USD;EUR;USDEUR45
6;JPY;HKD;JPYHKD33
7;JPY;RUB;JPYRUB83
8;ALL;AKU;ALLAKU24
9;AKU;RRR;AKURRR96
10;KKL;LOI;KKLLOI46"

d<-read.delim(textConnection(v),header=TRUE,sep=";",strip.white=TRUE,stringsAsFactors =F)
d
#   base_currency quote_currency  api_key
#1            USD            AUD USDAUD13
#2            USD            CAD USDCAD58
#3            EUR            CNY EURCNY99
#4            EUR            CZK EURCZK65
#5            USD            EUR USDEUR45
#6            JPY            HKD JPYHKD33
#7            JPY            RUB JPYRUB83
#8            ALL            AKU ALLAKU24
#9            AKU            RRR AKURRR96
#10           KKL            LOI KKLLOI46

#Select every currency that appears in the dataframe
all_cur <- c(d$base_currency, d$quote_currency)

#all_cur
# [1] "USD" "USD" "EUR" "EUR" "USD" "JPY" "JPY" "ALL" "AKU" "KKL" "AUD" "CAD" "CNY" "CZK" "EUR" "HKD" "RUB" "AKU" "RRR" "LOI"

#Select only unique items
all_cur_unique <- unique(all_cur)

#all_cur_unique
# [1] "USD" "EUR" "JPY" "ALL" "AKU" "KKL" "AUD" "CAD" "CNY" "CZK" "HKD" "RUB" "RRR" "LOI"


 #for each unique currency create a vector containing that currency and
 #each currency associated with it in a currency pair
 A <- lapply (as.list(all_cur_unique) , function (i) c(i,subset(d$base_currency, d$quote_currency == i), subset(d$quote_currency, d$base_currency == i)))

A
#
#[[1]]
#[1] "USD" "AUD" "CAD" "EUR"
#USD group : every currency in this vector can be converted in any other through USD
#
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "EUR" "USD" "CNY" "CZK"
#EUR group : every currency in this vector can be converted in any other through EUR
#
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "JPY" "HKD" "RUB"
#JPY group : every currency in this vector can be converted in any other through JPY
#
#
#[[4]]
#[1] "ALL" "AKU"
#
#[[5]]
#[1] "AKU" "ALL" "RRR"
#
#[[6]]
#[1] "KKL" "LOI"
#
#[[7]]
#[1] "AUD" "USD"
#
#[[8]]
#[1] "CAD" "USD"
#
#[[9]]
#[1] "CNY" "EUR"
#
#[[10]]
#[1] "CZK" "EUR"
#
#[[11]]
#[1] "HKD" "JPY"
#
#[[12]]
#[1] "RUB" "JPY"
#
#[[13]]
#[1] "RRR" "AKU"
#
#[[14]]
#[1] "LOI" "KKL"
```

Now using this list of vectors I need first to select every vector containing "USD" because USD must be in the "supported currencies", therfore i need these items:

```
[[1]]
[1] "USD" "AUD" "CAD" "EUR"

[[2]]
[1] "EUR" "USD" "CNY" "CZK"

[[7]]
[1] "AUD" "USD"

[[8]]
[1] "CAD" "USD"
```

Then I need to combine these vectors and select only unique occurences, I managed to do it like that:

```
B <- sapply(A, function(x) is.element('USD', x))
usd_convertible_list <- A[B]
usd_convertible_vector <- Reduce(c, usd_convertible_list)
usd_convertible_vector_unique <- unique(usd_convertible_vector)
usd_convertible_vector_unique

#    "USD" "AUD" "CAD" "EUR" "CNY" "CZK"
```

Then, for each currency in that vector, I need to again select each vector of the list containg that currency:

for "USD":

```
[[1]]
[1] "USD" "AUD" "CAD" "EUR"

[[2]]
[1] "EUR" "USD" "CNY" "CZK"

[[7]]
[1] "AUD" "USD"

[[8]]
[1] "CAD" "USD"
```

for "AUD":

```
[[1]]
[1] "USD" "AUD" "CAD" "EUR"

[[7]]
[1] "AUD" "USD"
```

for "CAD":

```
[[1]]
[1] "USD" "AUD" "CAD" "EUR"

[[8]]
[1] "CAD" "USD"
```

etc. for every currency in `"USD" "AUD" "CAD" "EUR" "CNY" "CZK"` then combine everything in a new vector, compare that vector with the previous one and if new currencies appears, repeat the operation.

When no new currencies are added to that vector that should means the list is complete and the loop should stop. With the currency pairs provided in the df as an example, the list is complete on the first run, but in case it's needed to go through multiple intermediate currency pairs to make a conversion, this process is needed I think.

For instance

```
USD    EUR
EUR    CNY
CNY    RUB
RUB    CHF
```

In this case, even that it doesn't seem obvious, every currency can be converted in any other. To get to it the loop needs to run 3 times when the first vector containing USD is selected.

I believe this process should give me the "supported currencies" vector I'm looking for but I struggle to turn this into code...

Comment: I see what you mean, I had this doubt while writing that you could have two separate groups. This is fun, I will try again.

Comment: @Cedric Haha yes, fun. it's quite challenging for me but not so fun anymore

Comment: Done a lot of progress trying a different way, but not yet there

Comment: OK there it is ! I hope it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
v<-"a;b;c
    1;USD;AUD;USDAUD13
    2;USD;CAD;USDCAD58
    3;EUR;CNY;EURCNY99
    4;EUR;CZK;EURCZK65
    5;USD;EUR;USDEUR45
    6;JPY;HKD;JPYHKD33
    7;JPY;RUB;JPYRUB83
    8;ALL;AKU;ALLAKU24
    9;AKU;RRR;AKURRR96
    10;KKL;LOI;KKLLOI46"
d<-read.delim(textConnection(v),header=TRUE,sep=";",strip.white=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
d<-d[,-3] # not needed
e<-d[,c(2,1)]; colnames(e)<-colnames(d)
f<-rbind(d,e) # since you can run both one way or the other, I create a data
# frame mixing to and fro
require(dplyr)
# this function will left join the df with itself using first and last 
# column
# at some point some lines will produce NA (no matching values)
# we will not join using those values, so I'm splitting the dataframe
# in two and working only with the one without NA in last column
my_left_join <-function(df){
  aa <- first(colnames(df))
  cc <- last(colnames(df))  
  df0 <- df[is.na(df[,ncol(df)]),] # we will not join NA
  df1 <- df[!is.na(df[,ncol(df)]),]
  df1 <- left_join(df1,df1[,c(1,ncol(df1))],by=setNames(aa,cc))
  df0[,last(colnames(df1))]<-rep(NA,nrow(df0))
  df2 <- rbind(df0,df1)
}
(g<-my_left_join(f))
#a   b b.y
#1  USD AUD USD
#2  USD CAD USD
#3  EUR CNY EUR
#4  EUR CZK EUR
#5  USD EUR CNY
#6  USD EUR CZK
#7  USD EUR USD
#8  JPY HKD JPY
#9  JPY RUB JPY
#10 ALL AKU RRR
#11 ALL AKU ALL
# here we see that we might run into loops, so let's remove values already in line
remove_duplicates_inrow <- function(df) {
  df[,ncol(df)]<-apply(df,1,function(X){
        if (X[length(X)]%in%X[1:(length(X)-1)])  X[length(X)]<-NA 
        return( X[length(X)])
      })
  return(df[order(df[ncol(df)]),])
}
(h<-ee(g))
#a   b  b.y
#35 RRR AKU  ALL
#17 CAD USD  AUD
#26 EUR USD  AUD
#15 AUD USD  CAD
#27 EUR USD  CAD
#5  USD EUR  CNY
#23 CZK EUR  CNY
#6  USD EUR  CZK
#21 CNY EUR  CZK
#16 AUD USD  EUR
#19 CAD USD  EUR
#31 RUB JPY  HKD
#10 ALL AKU  RRR
#30 HKD JPY  RUB
#22 CNY EUR  USD
#25 CZK EUR  USD
#1  USD AUD <NA>
#2  USD CAD <NA>
# this function will recursive left join untill there is no matching
# due to the way it is built I have to remove the last two columns
recursive_join <-function (df){
  #print(df)
  #browser()
  df <- my_left_join(df)
  df <- remove_duplicates_inrow(df)
  if (all(is.na(df[,ncol(df)]))){
    return(df[order(df[ncol(df)]),-ncol(df)])
  } else {
    recursive_join(df)
  }
}

i<-recursive_join(f)
# everything is a mix, I sort by row and by col to obtain the right order
# order by row
i<-t(apply(i,1,function(X)X[order(X)]))
# order by all columns, note this is a problem as we don't know in advance
# the number of columns, I have asked a question regarding this.
i<-i[order(i[,1],i[,2],i[,3],i[,4]),]
```

the latter assumes that we have only 4 columns, I have posted a question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47374892/sorting-a-matrix-with-order-using-all-columns-when-you-dont-know-the-number-o) asking how to do that if the number of column is unknown.
Below the adapted answer :

```
col=""
for (j in 1:ncol(i)){
  col <- paste(col,paste0( 'i[,',j,']' ), sep = "," )
}
## remove first comma
col <- substr(col,2,nchar(col))
i <- eval(parse(text= paste("A[order(",col,",decreasing=TRUE),]")))    



# now we have duplicated 
i<-i[!duplicated(i),]
# OK these duplicates were the easy ones, but we have vectors of different 
length, lets remove vector that are contained in longer vectors  

res<-matrix(i[1, ],1,ncol(i))
for (l in 2:nrow(i)){      
  # comparing line with last in res but remove NA
  # as we have sorted data this works !
  if (!all(i[l,][!is.na(i[l,])]
  %in%
  res[nrow(res),][!is.na(res[nrow(res),])])){    
    res<-rbind(res,i[l,]) 
  }  
}
res
#[,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
#[1,] "AKU" "ALL" "RRR" NA   
#[2,] "AUD" "CAD" "EUR" "USD"
#[3,] "CNY" "CZK" "EUR" "USD"
#[4,] "HKD" "JPY" "RUB" NA   
#[5,] "KKL" "LOI" NA    NA
```

Comment: Thank you @Cedric I added some fake currency pairs to see how your code reacted and something doesn't work... I edited my original post to show you what it outputed

Comment: Thank you so much @Cedric ! It seems to work. I'll take a deeper look at your code to figure out how it works. It souldn't be a problem with all the comments. Thank you again !

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask if you run into problem